# How to make a better battery-saving data update service for an android app

Tags: android, service, timer, battery

I am building an android app for fetching internet data and rendering it as a list. The data is changing every minute, so I made a service and used a Timer to load the data with an interval.

My question is that:

- I want to know when the app (not a particular activity) goes to the background, for example, user pressed the home button, in that case, I want to pause the service in order to save battery.
- I want to know when the phone is sleeping (screen dimmed), in that case, I would like to pause the service too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Pause your service in `onPause` (and resume in `onResume`).
2. Unless you have a wake lock, your app will not run when the phone is sleeping.
3. If you're bound to a foreground app, why use a service in the first place?

To elaborate on 1: I understand you're saying "app", not "a particular activity", but your best bet is to use `Activity.onPause` and `Activity.onResume`. If anything, you can add a short delay so that nothing happens if onPause is followed immediately by onResume.

Comment: I have question for 2), I used a AsyncTask to load data and postDelay a Runnable to reload it some seconds later when the load action finished. When I shutdown the phone screen, the task still are running and runing.